# Running two projects at once in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I develop web project. Server is node.js application written in TypeScript. Client also written in Typescript. I need two ability:

1. to compile different projects with different compiler options in different folders.
2. to debug both projects at the same time.

How can I do this?

Comment: Open two VSCode instances?

Comment: WebStorm and Visual Studio have ability for debugging more than one project within one instance

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnTF_n_SIOk

Answer (score 83):

See our documentation on multitarget debugging: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging

In your `launch.json`, just create a `compounds` section that contains the targets you want to debug

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Server",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Client",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/client.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": ["Server", "Client"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Its my understanding that launch.json is associated w a project.  If there are multiple projects, it seems redundant to have a componds sections in each launch.json.

Comment: For those looking at this in the future, the launch.json is associated with the workspace, not the project (at least it is now, I can't speak to how it was a year ago). This worked great, thanks!

Comment: Hello, I have a workspace which includes a React and a .NET project. How do I get them both to run at the same time?

Comment: thanks for this answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Im debugging my FastAPI application and celery worker using this.