# How to run .NET and React task simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, model-view-controller, visual-studio-code

I have a multi-root work space with the following structure:

```
    {
  "folders": [
    {
      "name": "client", //React using WSL2
      "path": "client"
    },
    {
      // Docs and release notes
      "name": "server", //.NET MVC
      "path": "server"
 }
]
```

Currently, I have to start each task (client and server task) separately. Is there a way to set VS Code so they both launch at the same time?

Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529937/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: No, they are separate projects.

Comment: I don't follow. Did you see the latest comment in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967232/3034273)?

Comment: I am using tasks, I think it is different.

Comment: From what I read, yes. And the launch.json needs to be at the workspace level, not project level

Comment: Yeah, its project level at the minute! I'm not sure how to take it up a level. I was also debating using a [depends] clause in one the tasks.json for either client/server. However, both projects seem to only be able to look relative to their own directories. Is this something you are familiar with?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much more than what I can read from the other answer. If you create a workspace, the launch.json would be at the top level while the projects are in separate folders. I'd suggest you try adding a comment on the other answer if you have other questions.