# How to run two Java files in VSCODE?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a basic java echo client server app and the textbook I'm reading says I should run the Server.java file first and then the Client.java second. But for some reason VSCode doesn't seem to be doing that. I run my Server.java file and get this which is what I'm expecting:

```
Simple Echo Server
Waiting for connection.....
```

And then I go to my Client.java file and run that, but nothing happens there are no errors, it stays at the two lines shown above, I can CTRL+C to terminate the batch job.

I'm expecting it to say this:

```
Simple Echo Server
Waiting for connection.....
Connected to client
```

But that's not happening - I am getting no errors though. I don't think it's a problem with my code since it's identical to the textbook's but I'll post it here.

Server.java

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    
    public class Server {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Simple Echo Server");
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000)) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for connection.....");
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected to client");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection.....");
            InetAddress localAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket(localAddress, 6000);
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))) {
            }
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {

        } // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```

Is it possible that VS code can't run two java files at one time?

*EDIT* Tried the dual configuration below, but the result is the same, nothing is changing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running two projects at once in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529937/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans are projects the same as files?

Comment: Clicking different java debug console in Terminal, you should see the result. Or cleaning java language server workspace from **Command Palette** then try again. Kindly let me know if you have any other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's achievable in VS Code.

Click [image] to create `launch.json`, keep the default configurations which should be similar to mine in the following picture then add `compounds` in it:

[image]

Turn to the selection box and choose compounds to run by clicking the left green triangle button, you'll get your wanted result:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this approach and sometimes the client will run before the server does. Is there any way to make the server run first ?

Comment: @ThinhTran. Are you sure that you put server be before client in `compound`? If still the same result, try cleaning java language server workspace from command palette then see if the question goes away.

Comment: @ThinhTran maybe add a Thread.sleep in the `main` of the client.