# VSCode debug api layer with View layer together

Tags: visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc, vscode-debugger

I have a project that I wrote with .net 5.0 MVC core.
I have Api , Core and View layers in my project.
For example, I call categories with api layer but when I debug view layer , i cant reach api layer.
So everytime i have to debug the api layer first. Then I need to debug the view again.
How can I compile both at the same time in debug mode?
I hope I could explain :( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VSCode supports only one `launch.json` , but you can have multiple launch configurations inside one `launch.json`.

here is a link can solve your problem.

[How to: Set multiple startup projects in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529937/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Xinran Shen Thank you for the response but I'm using VSCode. I dont use Visual Studio. how can i do this in VsCode ?

Comment: Hi @Lvnt, I have Edited my answer .